# Difficulty figuring out how to fetch an NSManagedObject subclass entity from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

**Description**

I'll admit that i am mainly guessing and trying to piece together things i find online to get the job done here. This job is very simple: I am trying to retrieve a single attribute from the entity "CrawlerOne" and set it to a UILabel.

**Code**

```
let key = "CrawlerDistance"
let request = NSFetchRequest<CrawlerOne>(entityName: "CrawlerOne")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
let resultPredicate = Predicate(format: "formUUID = %@" , key)
var compound = CompoundPredicate.init(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [resultPredicate])
var results:NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request, error:nil)
```

*Like i said, i undoubtably know this is wrong. I am trying to find an entity with the name "CrawlerDistance" using NSPredicate. I get an error message on the last like that says "Use of unresolved identifier 'context'." I am very lost and struggling here and would appreciate some guidance. I would really like to know if i am heading in the right direction with my thought process and/or what i need to get past this error/fix any issues.*

**This is written in swift 3 for excode beta 8.0**

**Saving**

*This is my code for saving the object i am trying to retrieve:*

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate)
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
let entity1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "CrawlerOne", into:context) as NSManagedObject as! CrawlerOne
entity1.crawlerDistance = distance.text
```

*This the CrawlerOne+CoreDataProperties.swift file*

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension CrawlerOne {

@nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CrawlerOne> {
return NSFetchRequest<CrawlerOne>(entityName: "CrawlerOne");
}

@NSManaged var crawlerAbrasion: String?
@NSManaged var crawlerDistance: String?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a code sample to compere to, without exactly explaining all the places that are wrong, and obviously i can't test this so some things may still be problematic...:

```
let targetValue = "CrawlerDistance"
let request = NSFetchRequest<CrawlerOne>(entityName: "CrawlerOne")
request.predicate = Predicate(format: "crawlerDistance = %@" , targetValue)

let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate)
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

var results:NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how i could take the 'results' array and actually apply it to a label. a simple label.text = results[i] type thing freezes the app. @Wain

Comment: freezes? use `first` to get the first result if it's available, but check it is before you use it

Comment: i am setting it up like : "let results:NSArray = try context.fetch(request)
            answers.text = results.firstObject as! String" and getting a print out of 'nil' as results.firstObject @Wain

Comment: the object isn't a string, its an instance of `CrawlerOne`

Comment: How would one go about grabbing the string saved in the entity? Sorry for all of the questions. I am a massive swift noob. @Wain

Comment: well, you set the text into it (`entity1.crawlerDistance = distance.text`) so you know how to get it out too - have confidence

Comment: Well thanks for your help! Maybe i will understand this mess soon! @Wain